rtracklayer: When using getTable(ucscTableQuery()) to download certain metadata I get the error “Error in errorHandler(responseError) : Bad Request”
I'm attempting to access specific data types from the ENCODE database for my chosen genes in a particular tissue/cell type (Lung fibroblasts) using the rtracklayer package. I can successfully retrieve Transcription and DNASE HS data for the genomic range of my gene, but I'm encountering errors when trying to access tracks such as "Bismap", "CpG Islands", and "Layered H3K27Ac/H3K4Me1/or H3K4Me3".
#### Load required libraries:

library(rtracklayer)
library(AnnotationHub)
library(Rsamtools)
library(GenomicRanges)
library(GenomicFeatures)

# STEP 1: Create a Browser Session:

session \<- browserSession("UCSC")

# STEP 2: Specify the genome assembly:

genome(session) \<- "hg38"

# STEP 3: Retrieve Track Names:

track.names \<- trackNames(ucscTableQuery(session))

# Save Light Gene Information: MFAP4 chr17:19,383,442-19,387,190

tlight \<- c(19383442, 19387190)
tlight_range \<- GRanges("chr17", IRanges(tlight\[1\], tlight\[2\]))

# Query for ATAC-seq data for Track "Layered H3K27Ac":

AC_query_tlight \<- getTable(ucscTableQuery(session,
    track = "Layered H3K27Ac",
    range = tlight_range,
    table = "wgEncodeBroadHistoneNhlfH3k27acStdSig"))

# Gives the error: Error in errorHandler(responseError) : Bad Request

# But for the below Track I am able to retrieve data using the same method:

TXN_tlight \<- getTable(ucscTableQuery(session,
    track = "Transcription",
    range = tlight_range,
    table = "wgEncodeRegTxnCaltechRnaSeqNhlfR2x75Il200SigPooled"))

# Output from TXN query:

head(TXN_tlight)
# > head(TXN_query)
#  start     end   value
# 1 6534512 6534513 169.648
# 2 6534513 6534514 230.490
# 3 6534514 6534515 237.152
# 4 6534515 6534516 260.245
# 5 6534516 6534517 262.465
# 6 6534517 6534522 273.124

However, while the TXN_tlight query works fine, I keep receiving a "Bad Request" error when attempting to retrieve data for the "Layered H3K27Ac" track. I've tried various approaches but haven't been able to resolve the issue.
Could someone help me understand why I'm encountering this error and suggest a solution? Additionally, if there are alternative methods for accessing these specific tracks, I'd appreciate any insights.
